# php str_replace for danish char's

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am removing danish special char's from a string, I have a string like this **1554896020A2å.pdf** danish char's are "æ ø å " for removing danish char's I am using **str_replace**, I successfully remove these two "æ ø" char's but I don't know this one "å" is not removed from the string. thanks for your help in advance.

I have used this to remove danish char's

```
$patterns = array('å', 'æ', 'ø');
$replacements = array('/x7D', 'X', '/x7C');
echo str_replace($patterns, $replacements, 1554896020A2å.pdf);
```

Comment: It looks like a two-byte "char": `a` plus a diacritic. Try adding `"a\u{030A}"` to the list of `$patterns`. See https://3v4l.org/A994q

Comment: so what can I do, do you have any idea?

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/A994q. Or `$patterns = array('å', "a\xCC\x8A", 'æ', 'ø');` will also do the job.

Comment: thanks, yes it works now, I have also it capital like "Å" what can I use for this

Comment: I added an answer. Feel free to adjust.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: Not sure if you need a regex here, but `/a\p{M}+/ui` will match all such `a`s with diacritics. See https://3v4l.org/Ni4dc

Comment: I have only danish char that's why I use only str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` you have in the string is not a single code unit, it is a code point consisting of two code units, `\xCC` and `\x8A`.

Thus, you may add this value to your patterns/replacements:

```
$patterns = array('å', "a\xCC\x8A", "A\xCC\x8A", 'Å', 'æ', 'ø');
$replacements = array('/x7D', '/x7D', '/x7D', '/x7D', 'X', '/x7C');
echo str_replace($patterns, $replacements, '1554896020A2å.pdf');
// => 1554896020A2/x7D.pdf
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/HRdfl)

In PHP 7, you may use `"a\u{030A}"` / `"A\u{030A}"` to match these `a` letters with their diacritic symbol.

Note that you may use `/a\p{M}+/ui` regex pattern with `preg_replace` if you decide to go with regex and match any `a`s followed with diacritic marks. `i` is for case insensitive matching, remove if not needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't know why it's not working all is working but for this Å its working in safari, do you have any idea?

Comment: @SalmanIqbal If it is a wide char (since Unicode code point) add it as is. I added it to the solution above.

Comment: it giving me this error. preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'a'

Comment: Why `preg_replace`? My example code is based on `str_replace`. Share the code via https://3v4l.org

Comment: it not working I have used " /A\p{M}+/ui " with str_replace.

Comment: `/A\p{M}+/ui` is a *regex*, it must be used with `preg_replace`. Share the code. Tell me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Share the link.